# Returning Object Property in Javascript Undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have this code:

```
function Tree() {
    this.capacity = 1;
    this.contents = 0;
    this.children = [];
    this.divided = false;

    this.pour = function(amount) {
        this.contents += amount;
        if (this.contents <= 1) {
            return;
        }

        if (!this.divided) {
            this.divide();
        }
        amount = this.contents - 1;
        this.contents = 1;
        for (let child in this.children) {
            this.children[child].pour(amount * .5);
        }
    }

    this.divide = function() {
        this.children = new Array(2).fill(0).map(x => new Tree());
        this.divided = true;
        return;
    }

    this.getContents = function(row, currentRow) {
        if (currentRow === undefined) {
            currentRow = 0;
        }

        if (row === currentRow) {
            console.log('Contents:', this.contents)
            return this.contents;
        }

        if (this.divided) {
            console.log(row, currentRow)
            currentRow++;
            this.children[0].getContents(row, currentRow);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Upon creating a tree, pouring into it, and getting its contents using this:

```
let tree = new Tree();
tree.pour(10);
tree.getContents(1);
```

It should return 1 because the second rows contents is 1. It logs 1 in the console but does not return the correct value. I am curious to what is going wrong.

Edit: I looked at switching it to a class and it did not solve the problem:

```
class Tree {
    constructor() {
        this.capacity = 1;
        this.contents = 0;
        this.children = [];
        this.divided = false;
    }

    pour(amount) {
        this.contents += amount;
        if (this.contents <= 1) {
            return;
        }

        if (!this.divided) {
            this.divide();
        }
        amount = this.contents - 1;
        this.contents = 1;
        for (let child in this.children) {
            this.children[child].pour(amount * .5);
        }
    }

    divide() {
        this.children = new Array(2).fill(0).map(x => new Tree());
        this.divided = true;
        return;
    }

    getContents(row, currentRow) {
        if (currentRow === undefined) {
            currentRow = 0;
        }

        if (row === currentRow) {
            console.log('Contents:', this.contents)
            return this.contents;
        }

        if (this.divided) {
            console.log(row, currentRow)
            currentRow++;
            this.children[0].getContents(row, currentRow);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any constructor considering your syntax (`new Tree()`)

Comment: I am confused to what this means because I thought that is what I was doing with the code. This is confusing to me because I can access the values within the properties but cannot return them.

Comment: Maybe time for a quick refresh @TheIncorrigible1 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: @Mark_M `$CURRENT_YEAR`, Mark_M, `$CURRENT_YEAR`! SHED YOUR ES1998 SKIN AND EMBRACE TRUE OOP CLASSES (/s, kind of)

Answer (score 2):

The `console.log` you are seeing is the result of this call:

```
 if (this.divided) {
        console.log(row, currentRow)
        currentRow++;
        this.children[0].getContents(row, currentRow); //<-- here
        // this is calling getContents() but ignores the return value
```

but in that case you don't actually return anything, so the inner `console.log()` fires but the return value is undefined.

I'm not really sure what the code is supposed to do, but returning a value when that condition is met results in a return value for the whole function:

```
if (this.divided) {
        console.log(row, currentRow)
        currentRow++;
        return this.children[0].getContents(row, currentRow);
```

Comment: Then how do I make it so when the row === currentRow it returns the correct result which is what I thought I was doing.

https://imgur.com/a/yjyfF is the result while the expected is 1 instead of undefined.

Comment: It will. But `currentRow` doesn't equal 1 until after that `if (this.divided)`

Answer (score 0):

It logs 1 to the console because you call

```
tree.pour(10)
```

Current row is undefined because you do not pass it in the argument

```
if (currentRow === undefined) {
        currentRow = 0;
    }

    if (row === currentRow) {
        console.log('Contents:->', this.contents)
        return this.contents;
    }
```

So it mean currentRow is 0 and row(1) is not equals to currentRow (0) which is why it returns undefined.

```
    } else {

        return;
    }
```